# Service dependency resets when the page is refreshed

Tags: dependency-injection, entity-framework-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, asp.net-core-identity

I have an **asp.net-core**, **Blazor Server Side** application, using **entity framework core** for database operations, and **microsoft identity** for authentication.

I am trying to get the current user in my application, and then access the user object directly from my DbContext.

I added the DbContext as a service

```
// Program.cs
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
});
```

Then used constructor injection to get the httpcontext, and set the user object

```
// Constructor injection
public DataContext(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
{
    // Find the current user
    var userId = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User?.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value;
    
    CurrentUser = this.Users.Where(x => x.Id == userId).Include(x => x.Location).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

This works fine, until I refresh the page.
When I do, the httpcontext gets reset, and is unable to find the current user. Is there a way to get around this problem, or another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store and fetch the `userid` from the [LocalStorage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/state-management?view=aspnetcore-7.0&pivots=server) if you want this value to persist during refresh.

> If the user reloads the page or closes and re-opens the browser, the
> state persists. If the user opens multiple browser tabs, the state is
> shared across the tabs. Data persists in localStorage until explicitly
> cleared.

Take a look at the [Service Lifetimes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-7.0#service-lifetime). What your experiencing is the default behavior for a scoped service.

> In the following component scenarios on the client, scoped services
> are reconstructed because a new circuit is created for the user:
>
> - The user closes the browser's window. The user opens a new window and    navigates back to the app.
> - The user closes a tab of the app in a    browser window. The user opens a new tab and navigates back to the    app.
> - **The user selects the browser's reload/refresh button.**

You could also define your service as a `Singleton` but you'll have to keep in mind this instance will be shared across all users. Depending on your needs / application it may be simpler to just use `LocalStorage`.